# Why my bootstrap.min.css file is not getting loaded in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am trying to load  `bootstrap.min.css` file in code igniter framework.I made folder as `assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.`.I am using URL helper function to load it.The code is as below

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php  base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>">
```

also tried as follow

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: did you use `base_url()`?

Comment: What's is the resulting code in html?

Comment: what url you get when you use second-one? (check your rendered html on broswer and tell)

Comment: I used base_url()when i view source it looks like     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://::1/project/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: @r.priya did you set `baseurl` from config file?

Comment: Actually bootstarp.min.css was built without spaces. So it should be so fast. better you should check your path and dependencies.

Comment: hit url of your project as ```http://127.0.0.1/project_name``` and then check...

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` if Ip is showing sometimes links will not show/work so best to set your base url

Answer (score 2):

CSS will be

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As above code your css should place like this

```
application
assets
    - css
        - bootstrap.min.css
    - js
        - ab.js
    - images
        - no_image_found.png
system
index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make the css (In my opinion you dont need to make any assets folder, only css folder is required) folder inside your project root directory. Put the code as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css">
```